# Joining `stdout` of from two commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do I join `stdout` of two commands? Eg. something like `cat file1 file2` but `file1` and `file2` being results of some manipulation, eg. something along the lines:

```
cat  "$(head file1)" "$(tail file1)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(cmd1;cmd2)` works for me, and doesn't uselessly use `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

To combine the stdout streams from those two commands and process both by a third command, say `tee`:

```
{ head file1; tail file1; } | tee logfile
```

Comment: Interesting, this is what i was doing but apparently the spaces after and before the curly braces matter.

Comment: Yes, @leosenko, those spaces are _essential_.   This is because curly braces are _reserved words_ but __not__ _metacharacters.   _Reserved words_ must be separated from other characters by either whitespace or a shell metacharacter.  Note also that the `;` before the closing `}` is required.  (The advantage of curly braces over parens is that, unless a subshell is needed, they don't force the creation of a subshell.)